# Is it possible to have multiple Jhipster UAA replicas in one micro-service cluster?

Tags: jhipster

I'm wondering if one can have multiple Jhipster UAA services in one cluster? If so, how the tokens produced for JWT be the same?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  When logging in, the requests are load-balanced through the gateway to the UAA.  It doesn't matter which UAA instance issues the token as long as it uses the same keystore.

Comment: But each UAA will automatically change its own privKey for signing tokens right? how do they synchronize?